# lxml.html.builder create a "template" tag

Tags: python, html, lxml

I have worked up until now with lxml.html.builder to create "div" and "p" tags but did not find out how to create a "template" tag. May someone help me because I don't know how to create such a tag and I do not understand the source code of it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose you are referring to the HTML5 `template` element (https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-template-element).

Comment: I think the problem is that the `template` element is not known by `lxml.html.builder`. See https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/html/builder.py.

Comment: I think I have found out a solution using lxml.etree to create an xml element. Looking like the following: `template_tag = etree.Element("template", id=tag_id)`. Its not the best way but its working.